# Multi teller model for hospital cashiers

Tags: java, finance, software-design, percona, bank

I'm currently ddeveloping a hospital managment system.
My application will have multi cashiers at the hospital who working 24/7, they collecting money from the patients & issuing a receipt voucher or returning money back to patient in case of refunding.

currently i'm storing the employee user account no for each transaction, at the end of the day the employee print a list of the transaction that he made with total of money he have to send to the accountant department.
but i need some one to tell me what is the polices needed to prevent any msitake with total amount that employee have in his/her cash box.

Do i need to prevent others from deleting or revesing the record even the head of the accounting department?

I thing i need something as bank tellers, but i can't find something to help me or explain to me what exactly i need to put in my polices for this part.

I'm using: Java as GUI & programming language, MySQL (Percona) as my database, Crystal Reports As my reporting & Printing solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to think about this a bit more atomically. Rather than there being transactions which can be edited or removed, just have actions which occur.

So sure have your people run a transaction in, and if someone wants to edit that transaction let them but do it as changeset, a bit like how version control systems work. So you still retain the information on the original transaction but then have the change that should be applied to that transaction.

If you have some base Id for the transaction/action and then each change set points to that then at least you can tie all changes together by date order and then run them to work out the total, which you can easily cache for performance purposes later on.

Whenever money is involved its VERY risky to allow editing or removal of data, which is why most places tend to retain all information and just either archive it as out of date and put a more up to date record in its place, or have some data trail of the original record and what has changed on it.

Ultimately it all comes down to tracability...

Comment: i think i need more logic in this, receipts & payments with POS applications not give any permission for the accountant to change any transactions done by the employee. you can edit invoices but not receipts. i really don't know how to analyse this situation.

Comment: Is this a university task or something, or is this a real world situation, as it sounds like quite a large system and if there is no analysis that has been done then I would say your setting yourself up for a huge fall here. You ideally need to map out the workflows through the system, so find out all possible scenarios, i.e Someone pays -> accounting invoices, Someone pays -> Someone edits -> Accounting invoices etc. Once you know the workflows you can see all the problems and then its just a case of solving them. The question in its current state is too broad to give you the answer you want.

Comment: This is a real world situation, patient pay for the medical invoice -> employee issuing a receipt voucher -> patient take the receipt voucher. After while the patient has a problem with receipt for example(receipt belong to another patient) patient returned to the hospital next day to the accounting department. so the action will be reversing the current receipt which mean cancel it & issuing a new one to the patient. the cancel will set a new employee to the transaction. so if want history of transactions for an employee it will not correct.